# Javascript: how can I return an empty string (i.e "")

Tags: javascript

I am making a function that returns greatest commmon prefix. When input is: `["flower","flow","flight"],` output should be: `"fl"`.
But there is an exception, when input is an empty array the output should be an empty string. This is where my function is not working.

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let prefix = '';
    let word = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
        for(let j = i + 1; j < strs.length; j++) {
          for (let k = 0; strs[i][k] === strs[j][k]; k++) {
              prefix += strs[i][k];
              //console.log(prefix);
          }
          prefix += ',';
          //console.log(prefix);
        }
    }
    prefix = prefix.split(',').sort().slice(1);
    console.log(prefix);
    // if(prefix[0].length === 0) {
    //     return "";
    // }
    return prefix[0];
};
console.log(longestCommonPrefix(["flower","flow","flight"]));
```

Comment: show full code please

Comment: my guess is that you have a callback function and you return a value inside of it, but its just a guess. show us your code

Comment: Posted the code @brk

Answer (score 3):

Following should work:

```
function returnEmptyIfNull(arr) {
    if(!arr?.length)
        return "";
    return "not empty";
}
```

Comment: What if `arr` isn't an array?

Comment: I answered the question, hopefully he will make it production ready by self.

Comment: Improved the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the array for `null` and a size of `0`. If either of these conditions are `true`, return an empty string.

```js
function joinItems(items) {
  return items == null || items.length === 0 ? '' : items.join(', ');
}

console.log(joinItems(['Hello', 'World'])); // "Hello, World"
console.log(joinItems([]));                 // ""
```

You can simplify this the the following expression:

```js
const joinItems = (items = []) => items?.join(', ') ?? '';

console.log(joinItems(['Hello', 'World'])); // "Hello, World"
console.log(joinItems());                   // ""
```

Answer (score 1):

`return ""` will return an empty string. If the function is returning undefined, there's something else wrong with your function.

```js
function fn () {
  return "";
}
console.log(typeof fn());
// 'string'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(param){
    if (param.length == 0){
        return "";
    }
}

console.log(check([]));
```

Works fine for me, check if the array is empty by checking if the length is 0.
You are getting undefined because your ' return "" ' line is not being run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your input is an array, then check that its length is 0.

```
function checkArrayIsEmpty(arr) {
    if(Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length === 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return "not an empty array";
    }
}
```

Comment: not an empty array won't help if it's not even an array.

Comment: @HamzaArshad we do not know the intent of the author's function, so the else block is a placeholder for demonstration purposes. Furthermore, "not an empty array" is logically sound even when the input is not an array, because strictly speaking, a non-array is not an array, nor an empty one.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strs.length==1)
  return strs[0]
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).